# The same app's Navigation Bar was different between two project

Tags: ios, navigation, uinavigationbar

Project 1:
[image: project 1]

Project 2:
[image: project 2]

I download a demo and try to use it in my project,but the navigation bar was different,different text font and different size.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I remove all IQKeyBoard things,and it become normal